# Query to return rows that are associated with many values in a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a relationship table with an unique ID  and two columns a and b, each being foreign keys to two entity tables A and B. The relationship is many to many between A and B, so the way the relationship table works now is that there are many rows that have an element of table A with different elements of table B, such as:

```
    <1>, <A1>, <B1>

    <2>, <A1>, <B5>

    <3>, <A1>, <B3>

    <4>, <A1>, <B150>

    <5>, <A1>, <B12>

    <6>, <A2>, <B72>

    . . .
```

Now I need a query that gives me the elements of type A that have corresponding rows with all the values in a set. So SELECT a FROM table WHERE b IN (B3, B17, ..., B178) is not what I want).
The reason is that this simple query returns the rows that have either of the values, but as in my question, I want the A entities that have rows with ALL the values of b in the input set (B3, B17, ..., B178).
In other words only the rows for which GROUP_CONCAT of column b when GROUP BY a is equal to the input set.

Also maybe it is good to mention that this input set starts with 2 values but will grow in each phase of my algorithm so in worst case it might have all the possible values for column b (although the result of this specific query for the worst case is most probably null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT a
FROM table
WHERE b IN (B3, B17, ..., B178)
GROUP BY a
HAVING COUNT(*) = <number of elements in the list>;
```

If your table can have duplicates, then you want `COUNT(DISTINCT b)`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond Gordon.
As far as I know, the IN has a functionality that returns any row that matches on column b with any of the values.

Now just to make sure about your respond, the HAVING section of the query is responsible for making sure that all the values are met, correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this in about 10hrs (it is late night here and I just got home).